# Set bounds as constraints in cplex python

Tags: python, cplex

I have a large mip problem (~50 constraints, 25k variables) of this form:

```
min c x, s.t. Ax = b, Gx <= h
```

I have built the vectores c,b,h and dicts A and G that represents the matrices (they are sparse matrices). The last rows of the matrix G are the bounds of the variables as constraints. There are binary, positive continuous and continuous variables in the model.

I used the cplex library to solve it, but for some reason the solution that I get when I set the bounds as constraints in the matrix G is not the same solution that I get when I set the bounds in the variables to the problem. Here is the pseudocode of what I am doing:

```
import cplex

class MyModel():
    ...
    def set_bounds_as_constraints(self):
        for col,_ in enumerate(self.c):
            if self.lbs[col] == self.ubs[col]:   # lbs[col] = var = ubs[col]  
                self.A.update((row_A,col):1)      
                self.b.append(self.lbs[col])
            else:                                # lbs[col] <= var <= ubs[col]  
                self.G.update((row,col):-1)
                self.b.append(-1*self.lbs[col]) # -var <= -lbs[col] == lbs[col] <= var
                self.G.update((row_G,col):1)      # var <= ubs[col]
                self.h.append(self.ubs[col])
    ...
    def set_problem(self):
        problem = cplex.Cplex()
        problem.set_problem_type(problem.problem_type.LP)
        problem.objective.set_sense(problem.objective.sense.minimize)
        
        # first method, this way the solver gives bad solutions
        problem.variables.add(obj=list(self.c.values()), types=self.types_vars, names=names_vars) 

        # second method, this way the solver seems to works fine 
        problem.variables.add(obj=list(self.c.values()), types=self.types_vars, lb=self.lb_vars, 
                              ub=self.ub_vars, names=names_vars)

        problem.linear_constraints.add ...
```

The first method correspond to set the bounds as constraints in the matrix G, and the second to have these constraints as lower and upper bounds when adding the variables to the model.

If I export the .lp files of both problem, the difference between them is that the second method add the bounds in the bottom of the file and the first creates constraints that the second method does not has, but I can see that the constraints that represents the bounds are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"I used the cplex library to solve it, but for some reason the solution that I get when I set the bounds as constraints in the matrix G is not the same solution that I get when I set the bounds in the variables to the problem."` Whats different? The *objective-value* or just the *solution-vector* while the objective is the same?

Comment: Both of them, the objetive value and the solution vector while the objetive is the same